# Code Changes for Implementing Kubernetes Probes

Tags: kubernetes, dotnet, healthcheck

I want to implement Kubernetes Liveliness Probes in my .Net core application with C# language. I understood that first I need to define the liveliness probe in deployment.yaml file of my application. I also created the http service in my application that is responding at 8080 port.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  labels:
    test: liveness
  name: liveness-http
spec:
  containers:
  - name: liveness
    image: k8s.gcr.io/liveness
    args:
    - /server
    livenessProbe:
      httpGet:
        path: /healthz
        port: 8080
        httpHeaders:
        - name: Custom-Header
          value: Awesome
      initialDelaySeconds: 3
      periodSeconds: 3
```

Apart from this what changes do I need to do in my C# code ? I am using below Kubernetes nuget in .csproj :

```
<PackageReference Include="KubernetesClient" Version="3.0.7" />
```

Comment: your app must respond to the defined health probe

Comment: @SathyajithBhat: what respond it shall do, is there any document that define the steps ?

Comment: It needs to respond with 200 status code. Your question is being down voted because you used image instead of code, edit the question and remove the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from @rohatgisanat [answer](https://devops.stackexchange.com/a/14134/28042) which explains the Kubernetes side, Microsoft did a pretty good job on explaining its own HC middleware on the service side: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/health-checks?view=aspnetcore-5.0

So the only thing for you to do is combine this knowledge :)

Answer (score 0):

Any code greater than or equal to 200 and less than 400 indicates success. Any other code indicates failure.

More info is found here :- [https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/#:~:text=The%20kubelet%20uses%20liveness%20probes,application%20more%20available%20despite%20bugs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/#:%7E:text=The%20kubelet%20uses%20liveness%20probes,application%20more%20available%20despite%20bugs).